# Updating all images in a Word Doc (.doc) using C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, shapes, office-interop, office-automation

I am building an application that iterates through a folder with a Word Document (.doc) if it finds an InlineShape (Picture) replace it with a new one. The program works fine, but I encountered a couple of document that has images with Warp Text set to be behind the text. Is there a way to detect pictures with warp text set to behind text?

Here is my current code

'''

```
class Program
{
    Application wordApp;
    Document doc;
    string imagePath = @"\\Your\Folder\Path";
    string folderPath = @"\\Your\Folder\Path";
    List<InlineShape> InlineShapesToDelete;                                                                                                   // List to hold inlines shapes to delete ( a picture, an OLE object, or an ActiveX control)


    public Program()
    {
        wordApp = new Application();
        InlineShapesToDelete = new List<InlineShape>();
    }// end of program construction
    public void Run()
    {
        try
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(folderPath))                                                                                           // Check if folder exists
            {
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.doc");                                                               // Get all .doc files in the folder
                foreach (string filePath in files)
                {
                    ProcessDocument(filePath);                                                                                          // Call ProcessDocument to process each .doc file
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Folder not found.");
            }
        }// end of outter try
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }// end of catch
        finally
        {
            CleanupApplication();                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        }// end of finally
    }// end of Run 
    private void ProcessDocument(string filePath)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"\nProcessing File: {Path.GetFileName(filePath)}");
        try
        {
            doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(filePath);                                                                                      // Open the Word document
            Console.WriteLine($"\tOpened File: {Path.GetFileName(filePath)}");
            InlineShapesToDelete.Clear();                                                                                                      // Reset shapes to delete for each document

            foreach (Section section in doc.Sections)
            {
                ProcessSection(section, filePath);                                                                                       // Iterate through all inline shapes in the section
            }

            if (InlineShapesToDelete.Count == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"\t\tNo Picture Found in doc {Path.GetFileName(filePath)}");
            }
            
            foreach (InlineShape shapeToDelete in InlineShapesToDelete)
            {   
                shapeToDelete.Delete();                                                                                                   // Delete the old pictures after iterating through all shapes
            }
            doc.Save();                                                                                                                   // Save Documents
            Console.WriteLine($"\t\t\tClosed File: {Path.GetFileName(filePath)}");
        }// end of inner try 
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: processing file {Path.GetFileName(filePath)}: {ex.Message}");
            
        }// end of catch
        finally
        {
            CleanupDocument();
        }// end of finally
    }// end of ProcessDocument
    private void ProcessSection(Section section, string filePath)
    {
        //bool replaced = false;
        int imageCount = 0;
        foreach (InlineShape shape in section.Range.InlineShapes)                                                                         // Iterate through all inline shapes in the section
        {
            if (shape.Type == WdInlineShapeType.wdInlineShapePicture)                                                                     // Check if the shape is a picture
            {
               
                shape.Select();
                InlineShapesToDelete.Add(shape);                                                                                          // Add the shape to delete list
                shape.Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(imagePath);                                                                           // Add new image
                imageCount++;
                Console.WriteLine($"\t\tImage \"{imageCount}\" Changed in file: {Path.GetFileName(filePath)}");
               // replaced = true; 
            }
        }
    }// end of ProcessSection
    
    private void CleanupDocument()
    {
        if (doc != null)
        {
            doc.Close();                                                                                                                  // Close Documents 
        }
    }// end of CleanupDocument
    private void CleanupApplication()
    {
        if (wordApp != null)
        {
            wordApp.Quit();                                                                                                               // Close Application
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wordApp);                                                                                            // Release COM Objects
        }
    }// end of CleanupApplication

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program program = new Program();
        program.Run();
    }
}
```

'''

Currently ProcessSection Method iterates through Section of the word doc and try to fine inlineShape object and if it finds an image it replace it with new one. This works for images that are set with default warp text (In line with text).

Any Suggestion ?

Comment: Try [Shape.TextFrame Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.shape.textframe?view=word-pia) returning [TextFrame object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.textframe?view=word-pia) having a [TextFrame.WarpFormat Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.textframe.warpformat?view=word-pia#microsoft-office-interop-word-textframe-warpformat) returning a [MsoWarpFormat Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.core.msowarpformat?view=office-pia).

Comment: However, I am not sure whether you can cast the `InlineShape` to `Shape`.

Comment: I tried doing that to check MsoWarpFormat still would not detect images with a different text wrapping other than "In Line with Text". I might tackle a different approach using DocumentFormat.OpenXml Library. Basically open the Word Doc as an XML and edit the image part. So far it's detected the images I am having issues with originally. But.. there is always a but, I am getting an issue " Error: processing file P242CP.doc: File contains corrupted data." So I need to figure out how to go around that.

Comment: *.doc is not XML. It should be *.docx. You could try save it as *.docx

Comment: Yeah, looks like I will need to go back to interop.word library. Since all the files I am trying to edit are .doc files. I can't just change it to .docx since they are old templates made for a company. Plus I tried changing it to .docx it just corrupts the whole file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution to this by using the Spire.doc library instead. For some reason, Microsoft.interop.word library in my case would not pick up images with "Warp text" format other than "In line with text". I switched to Spire.doc and was able to solve my issue by picking up all images and replacing them without any issues.